# PHP undefined index on first request

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I have a script that uses regex to get some value on a page retrieved with curl.

the code: `preg_match('/<h2>([\d\,]+)<\/h2>/', $curl_exec, $matches);`

When I `print_r($matches)` in my browser, it's always there.

I'm using this script in a cron job to get the results every 10 minutes. when I test it myself and use 'php script.php', it always says undefined index for the data i want to get, but if i do 'php script.php' a second time, it works. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Any work arounds?

```
$CurlHandle = curl_init($StatsUrl);
curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0");

$Data = curl_exec($CurlHandle);

preg_match("/<h2>([\d\,]+)<\/h2>/", $Data, $Matches);

print_r($Data);

if(!isset($Matches[1])) exit('Irrecoverable error.');

$PlayerCount = str_replace(",", "", $Matches[1]);

$CurrentTime = time();
```

Comment: Maybe my comment is kinda off-topic but I think it's useful. [Don't parse html with Regex, please](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283847)

Comment: yeah, yeah I know. that doesn't really solve my problem as I've used a DOM parser (simplehtmldom) etc, and the same thing happens.

Comment: Try adding `print_r($curl_exec)` to see what you're getting back from cURL.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. It shows nothing, blank. If I do it again right after, it loads the expected page.  I don't get it. I've reproduced this 10 times andit's always the same behavior.

Comment: @Steve Could you show more code? It's clear that problem is neither `preg_match`, not `print_r`.

Comment: added more code.  the check for Matches[1] was added as i first started diagnosing the problem, not before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what was originally causing the problem, but I added a `system('php script.php');` in the event of failure, so it calls it twice.  This is obviously a duct tape solution, but it's working.